# Is there a difference between "utf8::upgrade" and "is_utf8/decode 'latin1'"?

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8

Do these two code snippets the same thing?

```
utf8::upgrade( $s );
```

---

```
use Encode qw(is_utf8 decode);

$s = is_utf8( $s ) ? $s : decode( 'latin1', $s );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a copy and the implications of such aside, they're the same thing, but only because of how `decode('latin1', $_)` handles invalid latin1 strings such as `"\x90"`.

The expression returns something different (number of bytes used internally vs `$s`), but I presumed you're discarding that.

I hope you ask because you want to replace the latter with the former!